# Estimate for Levy metric

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities

In the [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Main_Page) there is an inequality for Levy metric ($d_L$):
$$d_L(E,F) \leq \{\beta_r(F)\}^{r/(r+1)},$$
where $E$ is a a distribution that is degenerate at zero, $\beta_r(F)$, $r>0$ is an absolute moment of the distribution $F$ (http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/L%C3%A9vy_metric).
I cannot prove this inequality. I can get only
$$d_L(E,F) \leq \{\beta_r(F)\}^{1/(r+1)}.$$
Do you have any ideas how to get  $r/(r+1)$?

Comment: Did you look at the references cited there?

Comment: Yes, I did. I found a proof for $r=2$ with estimate $1/3$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion in the definition of $\beta_r(X)$. It does not match with the estimate. The estimate of the Encyclopedia should be written for $\gamma_r(X)=E(|X|^r)^{1/r}$ in place of $\beta_r(X)=E(|X|^r)$. The inequality that you can prove is
$$d_L(E,F)\leq\gamma_r(F)^{\frac{r}{r+1}}.$$

On the other side, as we will see the same inequality is wrong for $\beta_r$. Let $F_\epsilon$ be uniform on $\{-\epsilon,+\epsilon\}$ and set $E$ the Dirac mass in $0$. You get $d_L(E,F_\epsilon)=\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon<1/2$ but also $\beta_r(F_\epsilon)=\epsilon^r$. Then $d_L\leq \beta_r^{r/(r+1)}$ simply writes
$$\epsilon\leq \epsilon^{\frac{r^2}{r+1}}.$$
This is of course wrong, for instance for $r=2$.

Conclusion: use $\gamma_r$ as definition of the $r$-th moment, or use $\beta_r$ and replace the estimate of the Encyclopiedia by your estimate.

Nicolas